# Database transactions in AngularJS/.NET Core architecture

Tags: angularjs, transactions, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

```
+==========+      +==========+      +=========+      +======+
+  Angular +<---->+ ASP.NET  +<---->+ Service +<---->+  EF  +<---->(Database)
+  Client  +      + Core API +      +  Layer  +      + Core +
+==========+      +==========+      +=========+      +======+
```

Question - where do you implement database transactions in an AngularJS/.NET Core architecture? (The diagram above illustrates a possible architecture.)

Sample Scenario - in one database transaction, you want to (1) insert one new customer record, (2) insert one new order record, and (3) insert two new order detail records.

Comment: You need to be more specific, which layer performs changes to database ? According to your information I guess is in the EF Core

Comment: I will use an example. Following is the process flow for inserting a customer record: (1) the Angular Client does an HTTP POST to the customer controller (in the ASP.NET Core API), (2) the customer controller calls the Service Layer which, in turn, calls the EF Core methods to add and commit the customer record to the database. There is no need for an explicit transaction, since there is only one record (and the call to EF SaveChanges() wraps the insert in an implicit transaction).

Comment: So, the problem comes in when I want to, for example, use a single transaction to insert multiple records into multiple tables. Where should the code go, which manages the transaction that inserts the multiple records?

Comment: Check this code, line 91: https://github.com/hherzl/EfCoreForEnterprise/blob/master/Code/Store/src/Store.Core/BusinessLayer/SalesBusinessObject.cs

Comment: Also you can check this guide: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1160586/EF-Core-for-Enterprise

Comment: Thank you – both links are very helpful. I want to ask you a follow up question using your SalesBusinessObject as an example. Let’s say that we have some type of JavaScript frontend (like Angular). How would this type of client call the CreateOrder method, passing in the Order and OrderDetail data?

Comment: @stickian: Avoid using words like "Create", "Delete", "Update" in methods/classes/commands or routes and prefer to use the domain's language (PlaceOrder, CancelOrder instead of CreateOrder, DeleteOrder). For example the "DeleteOrder" is quite unclear, why you may want to delete an order? This may be bad and for a business expert sounds like loss of data. When you say "CancelOrder" then its more obvious that the order still exists in the database but only was canceled

Comment: @tseng Thank for your feedback, I'll apply those fixes for my code

Comment: @stickian Have you resolved your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with client-sided code (JavaScript, Angular, etc.) you have to look at it from HTTP Protocol perspective. A single HTTP Request should be considered as one atomic operation (=transaction).

One reason for this is, that HTTP is a stateless protocol and by default doesn't persist a state and while you can work around it (sessions), it would violate RESTful principle to have a state (values saved in sessions, TempData etc). Everything required for are request should be passed with the request.

Also the default lifetime for ORMs like EntityFramework Core is "scoped", which means it is created when the request begins and disposed when the request ends. This is important for ACID/transaction operations and memory management (otherwise object will be tracked forever and cause memory leaks). As such, you should not tamper or try to work around this limitation.

That being said, if you want multiple operations from client-side (browser) to be treated as a single operation, you need to batch them together into a structure and then send it with a single request to the database.

However this can be a bit tricky to accomplish while staying true to RESTful service principles.

One way is to create a specialized ViewModel which will scope a transaction, let's call it `OrdersTransactionScopeViewModel` and instead of creating single `Order` and `OrderDetail` models you create one `OrderViewModel` model which contains both.

```
public class OrdersTransactionScopeViewModel
{
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public List<OrderViewModel> Orders { get; } = new List<OrderDetailViewModel>();
}

public class OrderViewModel 
{
    public List<OrderDetailViewModel> { get; } = new List<OrderDetailViewModel>();
    public ShippingMethod ShippingMethod { get; set; }
}

public class OrderDetailViewModel 
{
    public int OrderPosition { get; set; }
    public string PartNumber { get; set; }
    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Then collect it all on the client side and submit them at once.

```
{
    "customer": { "name": "Firstname", "lastname": "Lastname", "address": { ...},
    "order": [{
        orderDetails: [{
            "orderPosition": 1,
            "partNumber": "12345",
            "quantity": 2
        },{
            "orderPosition": 2,
            "partNumber": "11111",
            "quantity": 1
        },{
            "orderPosition": 1,
            "partNumber": "666",
            "quantity": 12
        }]
    }]
}
```

Then you have one single object sent to the REST service and you can handle it as one transaction. Read the properties, generate your persistence models from it and insert it.

I assume that when all of them are passed you consider the order to be placed and to be executed. The above works, but may not suitably cover the business requirements and can't track on what happened in particular.

Another way to approach it, is to not treat it as atomic operation.

For example:

- The user puts an item into the shopping cart (call POST /api/cart or POST /api/cart/{position:int} if you want it be idempotent)
- The user puts another item into the shopping cart
- The user checks out and is asked to add shipping address and payment method
- The user creates an account (call POST /api/register), if not existing
- The user gets an overview and has to confirm it (POST /api/cart/processOrder)

Each of the operations place the objects into a container (here shopping cart) and at the end you process it and get it from there and create the order.

This works a bit differently if the order is created by a worker of the company (i.e. the customer orders via phone) and the process is different.

There you don't have a shopping cart. The processing steps are similar though.

- The employee and opens a new order (POST /api/orders) and may receive an JSON response (that may contain state and a few things populated like current date, division and the employee id who opened it) like this

  ```
  {
      "orderId": "unique-guid",
      "createdOn": "2017-01-07T15:01:24",
      "createdBy": "employee-guid-here",
      "state": "open",
      "orderNum": null,
      "orderDetails": []
  }
  ```

  that's displays it to the employee.
- The employee takes the order from the customer and keeps adding new order details to it, each triggering a request to the API (POST /api/order/unique-guid)
- Once finished, employee asks the customer for his customer number. He checks it's existence (GET /api/customer/{id}). If its not found, he asks the customer for details and the result gets posted (POST /api/customer)
- Lastly, he asks the customer to confirm his order and hits "place order" button (PUT /api/order/unique-guid) and a orderNum is created once its successfully processed. The process changes from open to "placed" and a "orderPlacedOn" field is set
- If the customer decides not to order it, the employee hits cancel and notes as reason "Customer changed his mind" or "Prices too high" and the order will be marked as "canceled" or "closed"

In this case the order remains in the database, but you have additional business value. You can see all orders placed and for what reasons they were canceled (can be used to improve customer satisfaction in future and react on it) as well as track the time the employee used on this order w/o an RoI (important in order to improve the acquisition rate by reacting to the reasons why a order was cancelled).

In this case you work completely w/o transactions and gain additional business value. Also if the browser crashes or employee accidentally hits F5, nothing is lost (which may be the case with the single transaction approach above).

Answer (score 0):

Following thing could be your help.

1. First of all I would like to address that if you building your application for real project that you missing one important layer : repository layer. That comes between Service layer and EF layer.
2. You can consider EF layer as unit of work but in that case you have to expose it to Service layer so it would be nice you create unit of work concept as well.
3. Then at Service layer you can use Repository along with Unit of work. Here Unit of work will initiate transaction distribute among other repository.

http://www.aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Unit-Of-Work

You can find more example online.

Comment: The issue here isn't implementing it on the server side, but that the application runs on the client (Browser, JavaScript) and that several independent request should have been bundled to a single transaction. This doesn't work very well, due to the scoped nature of DbContext (and Singleton makes no sense from resource and performance point of view). So it's near impossible to spam a single transaction over lets say 5 http requests (create customer, create order, create 3 details)